# Deploying .war file in Websphere application server 6.1?

Tags: java, websphere, application-server

When i was trying to install new application in WAS 6.1, I have given the .war file i've created for SampleApplication.

The SampleApplication.war is successfully running in Tomcat server, but when i tried to deploy it in WAS 6.1, following error was shown.

```
The exception **IWAE0022E** Exception occurred loading deployment descriptor for module `"SampleApplication.war" in EAR file "C:\Appllications\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer2\profiles\AppSrv01\wstemp\3506402\upload\SampleApplication_war.ear" ocurred. Check log for details.`
```

The context root i've given as /SampleApplicaion.

So what would be the problem and how to resolve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

- check the log for more information as instructed
- if memory serves, WAS 6.1 is a Servlet 2.4 container, so check that the deployment descriptor (web.xml) validates against the 2.4 schema (or 2.3 or 2.2 DTD if you're writing to those specs)

Comment: +1 Yeah its worked McDowell.. I have configured my web.xml to Servlet 2.4 version. And now its fine.

Answer (score 2):

Found by googling [IWAE0022E](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258920)

Cause
The display-name tag should come before the servlet-name tag.

Resolving the problem
Load enterprise application in a developer tool and look at the web.xml
From web.xml in the WebSphere Application Resource (WAR) , the following is seen:

```
  <servlet-name>test_name</servlet-name>
  <display-name>test_displayname</display-name>
```

The correct order is: First "display-name" then "servlet-name",
like the example below:

```
  <display-name>test_displayname</display-name>
  <servlet-name>test_name</servlet-name>
```